# Can I use FieldSets to check for changes to a list of fields within an apex method?

Tags: apex, fieldsets

I have a scenario where in `before update` context I want to check a list of fields for changes. Normally I would simply compare the values between `newMap` and `oldMap` as such:

```
for(Record r : Trigger.new)
{
    if(Trigger.oldMap.get(r.Id).thisField__c != Trigger.newMap.get(r.Id).thisField__c) //The field value has been edited in this update
    {perform business logic}
}
```

It seems to me like this could be a great place to use FieldSets, so that I can easily add or remove fields that I want to check for edits in this loop, but all I can find is `FieldSetMember.getFieldPath()` which returns a string - that is great for use in a SOQL query, but what about here where I want to directly reference those fields in my apex code?

Is there any way to do this? I had imagined it looking something like this, but I've put `???` where I am at a loss for how to reference the field in question on the record within `newMap` or `oldMap`.

```
List<FieldSetMember> fieldsToCheck = Schema.SObjectType.Object.fieldSets.Fields_To_Check.getFields();

for(Record r : Trigger.new)
{
    for(FieldSetMember fsm : fieldsToCheck)
    {
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(r.Id).??? != Trigger.newMap.get(r.Id).???) //The field value has been edited in this update
        {perform business logic}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `getFieldPath` method:

```
for (FieldSetMember member : fieldsToCheck)
{
    String field = member.getFieldPath();
}
```

As for how to get a field's value when you have its name as a string, you would use the generic `SObject.get` method:

```
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    for (FieldSetMember member : fieldsToCheck)
    {
        Object newValue = record.get(member.getFieldPath());
    }
}
```

Note also that you are injecting quite a bit of inefficiency by calling `trigger.newMap.get(r.Id)`. That gives you the same exact variable as `r`.

```
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    for (FieldSetMember member : fieldsToCheck)
    {
        String field = member.getFieldPath();
        if (record.get(field) != trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).get(field))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also, I highly recommend you look into using the [`Selector`](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library. With it, you can simply do something like:

```
for (String member : fieldsToCheck)
{
    List<MyObject__c> changedRecords = Select.Field.hasChanged(member.getFieldPath())
        .filter(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
    // operate on this collection of records
    // containing only those whose value has changed
    // in the specific field in question
}
```

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant to mention `getFieldPath()` rather than `getLabel()` - will edit my post above.

However, I still don't see how I can use that where i have `???` in my second code block.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I see it now. Somehow the SObject.get() method has escaped my awareness all this time -_-.